# Is the inverse of continuous function on compact a continuous function?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(A,d_1)$ and $(B,d_2)$ two metric spaces anche $A$ is compact

Let $f:A \to B$ a continuous bijective function

Is it true that $f^{-1}$ is a continuous function ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: you have the following theorem:
if $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection, where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff (which holds for metric spaces), then $f$ is a homeomorphism (and hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous as required). For a reference: James Munkres: Topology, second edition, page 167, theorem 26.6.

Comment: ok @Student exhesaustive answer, thanks

Comment: The prove is actually not really hard, but requires that you know that 1) closed sets in a compact space are compact themselves 2) image of a compact space under a continuous function is compact itself and 3) a compact set in a Hausdorff space is closed. This proves that the image of a closed set is again closed, which shows that $f^{-1}$ is continuous :)

Comment: It is easy to flesh this out, thus not needing an external reference: it suffices to show that $f$ is _open_. Let $U\subset X$ be open, so $C=X-U$ is closed. A closed subset of compact $X$ is compact. The continuous image $f(X-U)$ of compact $X-U$ is compact. A compact subset of Hausdorff is closed. Thus $f(U)=Y-f(X-U)$ is open. Hence $f$ is open...

Comment: @paulgarrett: I had to look up the proof in the book (just remembered the statement). It used almost exactly the same you wrote down, apart from it starting with a closed subset of $X$ :)

Comment: @Student, it is a fairly amazing little result, I think.

Comment: @paulgarrett I absolutely agree with you!